# Tox fails while Nose passes

Tags: python, python-3.x, nose, tox

A bit of background: I'm trying to make my first contribution to an open source project.  I've written a bit of functionality and am trying to run the unittests per the contribution instructions.

My py2x code passes, my py3x code fails.

I installed a py3 interpreter and am trying to identify the issue.

Problem:

When running nosetests all of the 898 tests pass.  When I run tox, they fail with some failures completely unrelated issues.

I am not sure of my next steps?  I tried dropping in the debugger and putting a break point where it fails, but it skips right over that.  I cannot see anything wrong with the code, so I was hoping someone could point me in the direction of next steps to take.

Thanks!

Eg:

```
  py27: commands succeeded
ERROR:   py34: commands failed
  doc: commands succeeded
[master] $ nosetests
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
.............................................................................
...................................................

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
898 tests run in 1.692 seconds (898 tests passed)
[master] $ python --version
Python 3.4.3
```